# What happens when I have duplicated #include in .cpp file

Tags: c++, build, c-preprocessor

I work in a small company but we have services where we might have duplicated includes in .CPP files. Duplicated .h files does affect our compilation time?

Comment: Usually it doesn't affect compilation time in any noticable way.

Answer (score 3):

Duplicate `.h` file can cause redefinition errors. Either use:

```
#pragma once
```

Or any other [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

Answer (score 0):

The #include statement effectively gets replaced with the full text of the file being included, resulting in one huge file containing all the headers and your original file's contents. Usually, the time it takes to paste all that together is negligible.

However, this means that the code ends up in your file twice, unless you have a

```
#pragma once
```

in it, or protect it using

```
#ifndef MY_HEADER_NAME_H
#define MY_HEADER_NAME_H

// Actual header contents go here.

#endif /* MY_HEADER_NAME_H*/
```

Or use other similar constructs like Objective C's #import directive, all of which ensure that the contents of the header aren't compiled a second time if you include them twice. Otherwise, depending on your code, you'd get error messages about doubly defined structs and the like.

So unless your project or your header files are *huge*, or your compiler is exceptionally badly written, or your hard disk is exceptionally slow, including the same file twice is negligible when it comes to compilation time.